# How do I make a condition of reading a file past a certain line?

Tags: c#, file-io, controls

```
var targetGridView = dataGridView1;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line == "NEXTDATA")
    {
        targetGridView = dataGridView2;
        continue;
    }

    var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
    targetGridView.Rows.Add(text);
}
```

This example will make place data to 2 `DataGridViews`. I was wondering though, what if I could change a it so that after it reads "NEXTDATA" line it will do something else differently and append on other controls instead? The problem is that this will only work on DGVs. What if I want Text Boxes maybe or other controls after reaching this line? This is somewhat of a headache but I don't know what to use instead of var.

```
test,1,2,3,4,5,6,
testing,7,8,9,10,11,12,
working,13,14,15,16,17,18,
multiline,19,20,21,22,23,24,
NEXTDATA
see,25,26,36,46,56,66, // textBox1 (multiline)
program,7,8,9,10,11,12, // comboBox1
macroer,13,14,15,16,17,18, // checkBox1
```

So in this text file I want the last 3 lines to go to different controls lets say.

Comment: I know this may be hard to explain in words but I'm trying my best to explain though. If it's unclear about something please try to question here.

Comment: You need to decide what you want to append to.. otherwise you're in for a gigantic headache of reflection just to figure out if you can send data to a control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, if you're adding text to another control (like a `TextBox`), your logic for displaying it is going to be different than a `DataGridView`. So you can just separate the two pieces of logic. I'll try to reuse some of your code:

```
var isNextDataReached = false;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line == "NEXTDATA")
    {
        isNextDataReached = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (!isNextDataReached)
    {
        var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(text);
    }
    else
    {
        // separate logic to display text in another control
    }
}
```

At this point, your file and the code are starting to get a little hard to maintain.

You might want to start thinking about better ways to determine which control your data should go in, other than putting a special string in the middle of your text file.

---

Just saw your update. I assumed you wanted all the lines after the magic string to go into one separate control. But you want every line afterwards to potentially go to a bunch of separate controls.

I'm not sure what that means for a bunch of comma-separated data to be added to a `CheckBox` or an array of `TextBox` controls.

Comment: Actually it's multiline and I found a way to work it out so I don't have to use commas to spllit. `var text = line;`
`textBox1.Text += text;` With other controls it becomes harder since more if statements I'm assuming? Also, the problem mainly is that I want to keep this all in 1 file to save the "user's settings".

Comment: I'm not really sure about LINQ or XML in C#. I haven't really learned it yet. Why is it like much more efficient when using this example?

Comment: Oh I see thanks for this. I'll try to think of better ones next time. See the thing is, readers aren't going to edit the text file. All the writing is based off of my code.